# svn: E175002: Unable to connect to a repository and Unexpected HTTP status 400 'Bad request' in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: svn, ubuntu, subclipse, ubuntu-14.04

I upgraded my machine OS Ubuntu 12.04 to Ubuntu 14.o4. When i was using it svn was working with out any issues.

But now it works sometime. Sometime it is showing following error.

```
svn co http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/usvn/svn/TEST/trunk

svn: E175002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/usvn/svn/TEST/trunk'
svn: E175002: Unexpected HTTP status 400 'Bad request' on 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/usvn/svn/TEST/trunk'
```

- I can go through the browser normally. Actually it need some
  credentials.
- I use some mobile broad band. But it isn't use any
  proxy. Because it is working with fedora matchin. I check this issue
  in fedora. But it is working good.
- I tried to use subclipse 1.10.x. Sometime this may be its issue.

I did following things. I had search in web. I couldn't find correct solution for this.

- Remove `~/.subversion/auth` directory for clear svn cache.
- use `svn cleanup` command

How can i fix this problem?

Comment: You haven't specified the version of SVN client which you use.